# Resize Images in Magnolia CMS 5.0 (Not cropping)

Tags: image, content-management-system, resize, imaging, magnolia

Does anyone know how to resize an image in Magnolia CMS 5.0 without cropping it? I have handled to work with the Assets module and the options that it provides for adapting images to my preferences. However, it just provides (as far as I know) the option to crop and zoom those images. I wonder if that module is configurable to show those options? I attach a screnshot with the options that I can see in the Assets module. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Hey, wondering if anyone has an answer for this? I am urgent with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a bit odd, but the image editor doesn't resize images.

Instead, Magnolia is designed with the idea that editors will upload a single high-quality images and that Magnolia will generate variations of the image as needed by the site design.

Check out http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Responsive+Web+design#ResponsiveWebdesign-Optimizedimages for more details.

Also, if you want to get more timely answers, I'd recommend posting your questions to the Magnolia forums: http://forum.magnolia-cms.com